# Asp.Net /C# when is Å equal to A? (and É equal to E)

Tags: c#, culture, diacritics

i'm paging countries in an alfabet, so countries starting A-D, E-H etc.
But i also want to list åbrohw at the a, and ëpollewop at the e.
I tried string.startswith providing a stringcompare option, but it doesn't work...

i'm running under the sv-SE culture code, if that matters...

Michel

Comment: Isn't "How to remove diacritic marks from characters" a better title? Just suggesting this, don't want to modify a good title into something slightly better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [How do I remove diacritics (accents) from a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net) for the solution to create a version without the diacritics, which you can use for the comparisons (while still displaying the version with the diacritics).

Answer (score 4):

Oh yes, the culture matters. If you run the following:

```
List<string> letters = new List<string>() { "Å", "B", "A" };

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE");
letters.Sort();
Console.WriteLine("sv-SE:")
letters.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));   

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
letters.Sort();
Console.WriteLine("en-GB:")
letters.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

...you get the following output:

```
sv-SE:
A
B
Å
en-GB:
A
Å
B
```

Comment: +1 as I was going to answer - just use a culture that considers "A" and "Å" to be the same letter.

Answer (score 1):

Try using range selection instead of precise matching.

```
A: (firstLetter <= A)
B: (firstLetter > A) AND (firstLetter <= B)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to give a specific culture for sorting or write your own comparer for that. Default sorting order for Swedish puts å, ä, ö at the end.

Most likely you would like to decompose letters with diacritics and sort them as if they wouldn't have a diacritic mark.